# Go-to-Top Anchor link doesn't hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a go-to-top anchor link. Initially its position is fixed on the bottom right. Its visibility is hidden.

As soon as the web-page opens, and I scroll, the anchor link is visible.

**Expected behavior**: When I click the anchor link, it should go to top and change its visibility property back to hidden.

**Real Behavior**: When I click the anchor link, it goes to top but doesn't hide.

```css
#go-top-anchor {
  font-size: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 5%;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body onscroll="anchor_visible()">
  <div id="top" style="height:300px;">
    <p>You're at the top div</p>
  </div>
  <div style="height:300px;">
    <p>You're at the bottom div</p>
  </div>
  <a id="go-top-anchor" onclick="hide_near_top()">Go-to-top</a>
  <script>
    function anchor_visible() {
      document.getElementById("go-top-anchor").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    function hide_near_top() {
      location.href = "#top";
      document.getElementById("go-top-anchor").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if, rather than hide it when you click it, you just hide it when the window is scrolled near the top? You can use `window.scrollY`, and roll the two functions into one. I'm not convinced you need the other function, I'm sure you can do it with pure HTML.

```css
#go-top-anchor {
  font-size: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 5%;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body onscroll="anchor_visible()">
  <div id="top" style="height:300px;">
    <p>You're at the top div</p>
  </div>
  <div style="height:300px;">
    <p>You're at the bottom div</p>
  </div>
  <a id="go-top-anchor" onclick="hide_near_top()">Go-to-top</a>
  <script>
    // Whenever the page scrolls
    function anchor_visible() {
      // If the window is scrolled down (more than a 20px buffer)
      if(window.scrollY > 20){
        // Show your button
        document.getElementById("go-top-anchor").style.visibility = "visible";
      }else{
        // Otherwise, hide your button
        document.getElementById("go-top-anchor").style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }

    function hide_near_top() {
      location.href = "#top";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Although you're right I can imagine doing this in better ways. But I'm still unable to understand why anchor doesn't hide in my original implementation. Any thoughts what I could have done wrong?

Comment: @user8570772 I agree with you, it is a bit weird. I think the main thing is that the browser is _scrolling_ after  your `document.getElementById("go-top-anchor").style.visibility = "hidden";`. So it did hide, for a split second, then your other function `anchor_visible` kicked in, even though it was scrolling up. Maybe you could check if the user was scrolling _down_ instead? Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Show the `go-to-top` link only when the user scrolls down 10 pixels or more from the top of the page. `onscroll` event gets fired for any scroll event on the page that's why you have to check the scroll position to either show the `go-to-top` link.

`Element.scrollTop` is supported by more browsers than `window.scrollY`.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body onscroll="anchor_visible()">
  <div id="top" style="height:300px;">
    <p>You're at the top div</p>
  </div>
  <div style="height:300px;">
    <p>You're at the bottom div</p>
  </div>
  <a id="go-top-anchor" onclick="hide_near_top()">Go-to-top</a>
  <script>
    function anchor_visible() {
      // Check if the user scrolled down 10 pixels or more from the top of the page
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 10)
        document.getElementById("go-top-anchor").style.visibility = "visible";    
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    function hide_near_top() {
      location.href = "#top";
      document.getElementById("go-top-anchor").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```